# Backflow Orifice (Zeta)

Tags: modelica, dymola

I would like to simulate 3 pumps and a pressure sink. The problem now is if I want the pump to pump the medium in the opposite direction(backflow), the orifice does not work anymore... 
Can anyone please help me?

Picture of the [model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56N6i.png)

Picture of the [signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mM0GY.png)

This is the error message:

```
Log-file of program ./dymosim
(generated: Thu Mar 08 09:21:33 2018)

dymosim started
... "dsin.txt" loading (dymosim input file)
Residual component 1 of system 1 is 1.255542e+002
Residual component 2 of system 1 is 1.255542e+002
Residual component 3 of system 1 is 1.255542e+002
LINEAR SYSTEM OF EQUATIONS IS SINGULAR AT TIME = 0
...    Linear system of equations number = 

... Variables which cannot be uniquely computed:
pump.port_a.h_outflow = 83680
... NOT ACCEPTING SINCE TOO LARGE RESDIUAL
Trying to solve non-linear system using global homotopy-method.
Residual component 1 of system 1 is 1.255542e+002
Residual component 2 of system 1 is 1.255542e+002
Residual component 3 of system 1 is 1.255542e+002
LINEAR SYSTEM OF EQUATIONS IS SINGULAR AT TIME = 0
...    Linear system of equations number = 1
... Variables which cannot be uniquely computed:
pump.port_a.h_outflow = 83680
... NOT ACCEPTING SINCE TOO LARGE RESDIUAL
Error: Failed to start model.
```

Comment: Two comments on you model: 1) You need a heat sink to remove the heat generated from the pumps (η < 1). You could replace the orifice with a Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe with a simple pressure drop model and a constant heat transfer coefficient, connected to a fixed ambient temperature. 2) I'm not sure that the pump models can reverse — you should test that in an "open-loop" model with one pump connected to two pressure boundaries.

Comment: Thank you for your held! I will test it as soon as possible...
The pumps are able to pump backwards, I already tested it.

Comment: Note that even if they can pump backwards it might still be that they are limited in how much they can pump backwards.